# Unable to send email in Joomla using Gmail SMTP settings. Getting SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. How to fix this?

Tags: smtp, gmail

MY joomla contact form gmail SMTP settings not working..see below that message showing when submitting contact form. What should be the reason?
extension=php_openssl.dll also enabled..

Error message -:
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answ ... swer=14257 c6sm7639242obl.22

I used these settings in joomla mail settings

Mailer: smtp
SMTP Authentication: yes
SMTP Security: SSL
SMTP Port: 465
SMTP Username: My gmail full address
SMTP Password: My gmail password
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Try to set host as 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'. It heped me once with a similar problem

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to enable 2FA in google and use the following settings.

You will need to generate an application specific password after configuring 2 factor authentication and use as password in the SMTP configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me after setting up 2FA and the app-specific password. It is also possible to use SSL with port 465.

Answer (score 3):

The first time you attempt to connect programmatically through an Application Google
will block it and send you an alert from your account.

Sign into that account through your browser and select approve the sign-in and you should be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Go to - "https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps" while you are logged in to gmail and from same browser. Click on "Turn On".

Comment: While this also solves the issue, I'd recommend to go for the more secure proposed solution using 2FA + app-specific password.