# c++ libcurl sent smtp mail using github library fails

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am trying to use the code given in [this git repository](https://github.com/honeyligo/curlsmtp.git). The code is not mine and I would like to thank honeyligo for his work!

I unfortunately can't manage to run it properly (I had to fix some compilation issues but nothing dramatic).

After setting the main.cpp to

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "curlsmtp.h"

int main(){
    CurlSmtp* mail = new CurlSmtp(
                "MYADDRESS@gmail.com",
                "MYPASSWORD",
                { "foo@yahoo.fr" },
                {},
                {},
                {},
                "it's a subject",
                "hello world you aredfsf",
                "smtp.gmail.com",
                "465");

    mail->send_mail();
    sleep(3);
    delete mail;

    return 0;
}
```

it constantly returns

```
* Expire in 200 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558a3b95d7e0)
```

then fails after a timeout. The code is roughly 500 lines long and well commented but I can't figure out why it fails. I don't know much about curl but I'm looking for a way to automatically sent mails with a pdf attached to my high school students. I need to implement a c++ solution because this will be part of a larger project.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might not be ale to figure out the 500 lines of code but you still have the advantage over me since you can actually see the code. It's not generally possible to answer questions about code without seeing the code.

Comment: "code given in this git repository" - was 'this' supposed to be a link to the repository?

Comment: Ohhh sorry!!!! yes, it was supposed to be a link! My bad! I correct that! I btw like your humor @john!

Comment: can you try port 587?

Comment: @ezegoing same outcome...

Comment: What kind of password are you using? If you have 2FA enabled in your Google account, you should use a generated application password for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658193/7262969

Comment: no 2FA, just username and password

Answer (score 3):

After some testing with curl both from the CLI and in a C app using libcurl, I found the issue: gmail only accepts smtp requests if you explicitly use smtps (`smtps://smtp.gmail.com`).
As it's hardcoded in this curlsmtp lib to use `smtp://`, you either modify it (`set_curl_option` method) or use libcurl directly (an easy example here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mime.html)

Also, you either have to set up 2FA in your Google account and create an app password, or enable access for less secure apps if there is no 2FA (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Comment: thx but I tried with your advice and it didn't help. Aadding the missing `s` to `smtp` in the library does not change anything for me. And the 2FA setting is 'Allow less secure apps: ON' for my gmail account. Did you use the exact code I gave?

Comment: Well, I have 2FA so I used an app password, but with that it worked fine for me after changing the lib code to `smtps://`.

Comment: I created a throwaway gmail account to test without 2 factor authentication, it still works for me.

Comment: This is the code I used for testing: https://pastebin.com/yBeSeRPs

It contains 2 methods, one of them is the code you posted, the other is a modified version of the curl smtp-mime example code. Both worked for me, either with or without 2FA

Comment: thx again but the code you propose uses `curl_easy_perform` to send the mail where the github code that is referenced uses `curl_multi_perform`. This is where I have the problem!

Comment: As I said, the code that you posted in the question (which is in my `curlsmtp()` test function) works just as well as the direct use of libcurl. If it doesn't work for you, it's most likely not a coding issue, but something else.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the libcurl smtp-mime code already? Does it have the same issue as yours?

Comment: thank your for your time, you're really helping! I tried the two versions of the code you provided. It successfully sends a mail with your `curl()` function but keeps on failing with your `curlsmtp()` function even with `smpts://` hardcoded. Your `curl` function works also when a pdf is attached to the mail. There is something wrong with the `curl_multi_perform` in the linked github library.

Comment: Even if my problem is not solved, you deserve the bounty because you helped me! thx

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for not being able to solve the whole issue.